# Multiple page switching in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, switching

Consider i am using five screen pages for project "A".Each page is having switching between other pages sequentially one by one,my need is to do close all the page when i am clicking the button "exit" from the page five which is the last one.

I have used this below code,but the problem is only the last page is getting close others are not.

find my code below

```
Button extbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but_Exit);
extbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}   });
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: hi @andro prabu why are you using setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);??? if it dont have any special work in your sample project please use "StartActivity(intent); finish(); " after every successful page redirection. then you wont get this problem in mere feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make all five activities extend a BaseActivity that registers a `BroadcastReceiver` at onCreate (and unregisters at onDestroy). 
When `extbtn` is clicked, send a broadcast to all those BaseActivities to close themselves

for example, in your BaseActivity add:

```
public static final String ACTION_KILL_COMMAND = "ACTION_KILL_COMMAND";
public static final String ACTION_KILL_DATATYPE = "content://ACTION_KILL_DATATYPE";

private KillReceiver mKillReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    ...
    ...
    mKillReceiver = new KillReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mKillReceiver, IntentFilter.create(ACTION_KILL_COMMAND, ACTION_KILL_DATATYPE));        
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mKillReceiver);
}

private final class KillReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

and at extbtn's onClick call:

```
extbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // send a broadcast that will finish activities at the bottom of the stack
        Intent killIntent = new Intent(BaseActivity.ACTION_KILL_COMMAND);
        killIntent.setType(BaseActivity.ACTION_KILL_DATATYPE);
        sendBroadcast(killIntent);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any thing to mention on manifest.xml if i follow your solution?